# How can the image and pdf files be made downloadable

Tags: php, html

Generally, browsers show the image and pdf files without embedding them in html. I need some codes to make these files not to show in the browsers but make them downloadable like doc files.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: well.. if we browse the url of the image or pdf file, we can view the file in browser without embedding them in html. i don't want this to happen. i want the files to be made downloadable when browsed.

Comment: i deleted the comment you are replying to as i worked it out, many examples how below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one :

```
$file = 'youfile.fileextention';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
```

Comment: I believe a better Content-Type would be application/force-download. octet-stream is supposed to be used for executable files.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't up to you, it is up to the browser.

However, you can make a suggestion as to what to do with it by setting the `content-disposition` header...

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"yourfilename.pdf\"");
```

Read the doc on the `header()` function:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

In case this isn't clear... this is for whatever resource is returned by the PHP document.  You may need a `readfile()` in there to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Set a couple of headers:

```
$filename = ...;
$mime_type = ...; //whichever applicable MIME type
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: $mime_type");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));  
readfile($filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile('myfile.pdf');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to send a  content type header to make the browser download the file.

If you aren't' generating it dynamically, you will need to read it off the disk first.

```
$fullPath = "/path/to/file/on/server.pdf";
$fsize = filesize($fullPath); 
$content = file_get_contents($fullPath);
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".$fsize); 
echo $content;
```